# Update position of a marker without adding a new one

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, marker

How to update a position of my marker in Google Maps v2 in android without adding a new one?
Every time my location changes i have to update the position of the user in a Google Map, but it always creating a new point e the map, how to avoid this behaviour?

Here is how im updating

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    this.localizacao = location;
    loc = location;
    if (mAdapter.getCount() == 0){
        getAdvsFromServer();
    }

    LatLng me = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    if (eu != null){
        Log.d("marker_eu", "removed");
        eu.remove();
    }
    eu = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(me).title("Eu"));
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_maps_indicator_current_position);
    eu.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bm));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(me));
    //map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(me, 13));
}
```

UPDATE:
This way it always creating a new point too:

```
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            this.localizacao = location;
            loc = location;
            if (mAdapter.getCount() == 0){
                getAdvsFromServer();
            }

            if (ac != null){
                ac.setLayoutLocalizacaoVisible(View.GONE, View.VISIBLE);
            }

            LatLng me = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

//          if (eu != null){
//              Log.d("marker_eu", "removed");
//              eu.remove();
//          }

            if (eu == null){
                eu = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(me).title("Eu"));
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_maps_indicator_current_position);
                eu.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bm));
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(me, 13));
            }else {
                eu.setPosition(me);
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(me));
            }
```

Comment: Try `map.clear();` inside onLocationChanged()!

Comment: map.clear() will clear more than i want.
I tried this before, and just crashs the app.
I just dont know why is not removing the point, because the method is being called.

Answer (score 1):

You should not add new marker every time location change, instead you can directly set the new position into your existing marker.

For example:

```
marker.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));
```

Comment: Ok, but if you look carefully i'm removing the old one.

Comment: @WitaloBenicio Have you mentioned this thing in your question why are you removing and adding again?

Comment: Its because i tried to only update position by setPosition() and it was creating a new poiting.

Answer (score 0):

If your activity is creating a new Marker while running this method, than `eu` is somehow cleared or null going into the if statement. `eu.setPosition(me);`would not create another Marker but simply change the location of the marker without altering any other attributes.

If you are certain that the new marker is not created somewhere else in your code then check the state of eu before going into your if statement and find out why it is null at that point by backtracking. Check the position of the Marker to verify the location after the execution. Use the following and watch the logcat.

```
System.out.println(eu);
```